# webdriverio findelements and $$ options are returning a Typescript error getText is not a function

Tags: webdriver-io

I have the below html tag generated as part of highchart

```
<g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels " data-z-index="7">
<text x="332.3333333333367" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:13;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="246" opacity="1">60</text>
<text x="886.9999999999668" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:13;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="246" opacity="1">65</text>
<text x="1441.6666666666667" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:13;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="246" opacity="1">70</text>
</g>
```

I am trying to extract all the text values in it and used the below command

```
xAxis =  $('.highcharts-xaxis-labels').$$('text').getText();
```

I tried the browser.findelements using the XPATH as well. But with both I am getting the error message

> TypeError: $(...).$$(...).getText is not a function

Comment: Can you please try below script for selector, I think this will be solve your problem. 

xAxis =  $('.highcharts-xaxis-labels text').getText();

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `$$` (an alias for `getElements`) returns an array of elements, not just one element. An element has a `getText()` method, but an array doesn't have that.

If you want to get a list of all the values, you need to map the list of elements to each element's value:

```
$('.highcharts-xaxis-labels').$$('text').map(textElement => textElement.getText());
```